# Export excel data to sharepoint 2013 list

Tags: javascript, excel, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

How to extract data from excel into a SharePoint 2013 list using JavaScript?
There are 6 fields in excel and the data from these 6 fields should be exported to the SharePoint 2013 list

Answer (score 0):

How about adding new list using Import Spreadsheet from Add an App.

You would not need any JS to do so.